# docker-compose up fails with "UnixHTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=None): Pool is closed"

Tags: docker

I'm getting the following error when performing "docker-compose up". This seem to be a random problem. The version of docker-compose is "1.8.0, build f3628c7" and Linux version is "Linux 3.10.0-327.13.1.el7.x86_64".

```
  ERROR: for scheduler  UnixHTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=None): Pool is closed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 61, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 113, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 835, in up
  File "compose/project.py", line 400, in up
  File "compose/parallel.py", line 64, in parallel_execute
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ClosedPoolError: UnixHTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=None): Pool is closed.
```

Although this issue is reported in docker github page, no insight into the resolution of the issue is mentioned. Any help to resolve this issue is appreciated.

Comment: I believe you'll have better luck working directly with the devs on github.

Comment: related to https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1923

Comment: I solved it by upgrading to `1.12`, had the issue with `1.11`